# Use Simple Product Price in Backend Orders

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, admin-order-create

When creating an order in the Magento admin using a configurable product, is it possible to use the simple product price instead of the configurable product price ? I have found an extension for using the simple product price when placing an order in the front end but that functionality does not apply when placing an order in the admin.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Out of box, no but there are extensions out there that does what you're looking for. I've never used any of them, but this is one of them.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-product-pricing.html

Comment: Thanks! I have used this one and it works briliiantly on the front end but when placing an order in the back end the out of the box functionality kicks in.